# Why is this deemed Off topic - is handling mail to a domain not an acceptable web master task?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, specific-question

The question on ProWebmasters: `https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8335/what-is-the-aim-of-this-email-is-this-a-ping-sping` ([link to question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8335/what-is-the-aim-of-this-email-is-this-a-ping-sping)) has been closed as off-topic. I was asking it in case someone had some background information or knowledge about spam practises.

> Hi, I received this spam in my
>   catch-all (All headers and full message in the original question).
>   As a webmaster of the
>   domain it was sent to, I am really
>   curious what the reason for this mail
>   is. It was sent to a non-existent user
>   "tania" on my domain - here I used
>   mydomain.zzz - what do the sender want
>   to achieve? Since many mail servers
>   have stopped backscattering, not
>   getting a bounce would not mean
>   anything, would it?
>
> And if this is off topic, where inb
>   the StackExchange WOULD it be on
>   topic?

---

### UPDATE: Moved it to ServerFault

### UPDATE: they ALSO found it off topic. Great :(

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether or not it is on-topic, I'm not sure I even *understand* your question.

It is "here is this random spam email, what does it mean?"

Comment: Please see revised meta and question

Comment: @mpl I suppose it is http://serverfault.com then, as hardcore email diagnostics would be best served there.

Comment: Ok thanks. That would have been great to know - or the closer could even have transferred it there...

Comment: @mpl best to move it or ask it during US business hours when sf.com will be busiest, so ~4-5 hours from now.

Comment: No luck there either